# Map properties to state in react-redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a component that uses `state` to provide data to user. For example `<div>this.state.variableInState</div>`. This component can dispatch some method (for example on `onClick` action). I'm currently using `react-redux` an `connect` method to map `store` to `props`. Is there a way I can `setState` after dispatch?

```
// actions
export function executeAction() {
  return function (dispatch, getState) {
    dispatch({
      type: 'MY_ACTION',
      payload: axios.get('/some/url')
    });
  };
}
// reducer

export default function (state = {}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'MY_ACTION_FULFILLED':
      return {...state, myVariable: action.payload.data}
  }
}
//component
class MyComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    (<div onClick={this.props.executeAction.bind(this)}>
      {this.state.variableInState}
      </div>)
  }

  someOtherMethod() {
    // I want to operate with state here, not with props
    // that's why my div gets state from this.state instead of this.props
    this.setState({variableInState: 'someValue'})
  }
}


export default connect((state, ownProperties) => {
  return {
    // So I want to change MyComponent.state.variableInState here
    // but this method updates MyComponent props only
    // What can I do?
    variableInProps: state.myVariable
  }
}, {executeAction})(MyComponent);
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Whatever i understand, all you want to do is to convert the component's props to component's own state. You can always change the component's props to component's state in the `componentWillReceiveProps` life cycle method in component like this.

```
//component
class MyComponent extends Component {
  componentWillReceiveProps(newProps){
     if(newProps.variableInProps != this.props.variableInProps){
         this.setState({variableInState: newProps.variableInProps })
     }
  }
  render() {
    (<div onClick={this.props.executeAction.bind(this)}>
      {this.state.variableInState}
      </div>)
  }

  someOtherMethod() {
    // I want to operate with state here, not with props
    // that's why my div gets state from this.state instead of this.props
    this.setState({variableInState: 'someValue'})
  }
}


export default connect((state, ownProperties) => {
  return {
    // So I want to change MyComponent.state.variableInState here
    // but this method updates MyComponent props only
    // What can I do?
    variableInProps: state.myVariable
  }
}, {executeAction})(MyComponent);
```

`componentWillReceiveProps` method is always executed by react whenever a new props is coming to component so this is the right place to update your component's state according to your props.

**UPDATE :**

The `componentWillReceiveProps` has been deprecated. So instead of this method you can use `componentDidUpdate` method to do this. `componentDidUpdate` method takes previous props and previous state as arguments. So you can check for the change in props and then set the state.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if(prevProps.variableInProps !== this.props.variableInProps){
    this.setState({variableInState: this.props.variableInProps })
  }
}
```

Comment: `componentWillReceiveProps` is already deprecated, you may use `componentDidUpdate` instead,

Answer (score 2):

I think you're not supposed to directly change the state like this. why not call another action to perform what you want?

The state should be immutable when using Redux. You should dispatch an action. A Reducer should receive the action and the current state, and return a new state object that includes the changes you want to make.
Check this: http://redux.js.org/docs/introduction/ThreePrinciples.html#changes-are-made-with-pure-functions

Comment: But how do I change the state via dispatch? My reducer already returns new state, but this state maps to props, not to state. How do I map it to state as well?

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can, onClick bind to some function like so:

```
onClick={this.myfunction.bind(this)}
```

Then define this myfuntion to be:

```
myfunction() {
    this.setState({ somestate: value });
    this.props.executeAction();
}
```

Here setState changes native component state, and calling action will change redux state if so defined by reducer. These states are independent.

Connect wrapper (first argument) maps state to props (redux state to react props) not component state itself.

Good question is why you need both, sure there are some examples where this could be useful...

In general if you need state that is needed globally then use redux state (easily applied to all components) and for some local states use react native state. (For example when you build some ui components like custom checkbox)

Comment: The state depends on rest response. Which is executed via dispatch

Comment: To be precise redux reducer will not change native component (react state) nor it should, what I wrote is a case when you want to dispatch some action but also change native react state.

Answer (score 0):

There's also **static [getDerivedStateFromProps](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops)**:

```
static getDerivedStateFromProp(nextProps, prevState) {
  return {stateVar: nextProps.var} // this will propagate as component state
}
```