# Redux props set to state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

How can I copy data from Redux props to state in component?

My code: https://pastebin.com/N9J1GP6e

cause:

```
this.state = {
        email: props.data.data.email
}
```

not working

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Map properties to state in react-redux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43146163/map-properties-to-state-in-react-redux)

Comment: shouldn't it be `this.props.data.data.email` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably don't need to do this since when your state from the `react-redux` `connect` changes, it will also change the `props` you receive in your `Profil` component, which will cause the re-render that you probably want.

If you still want for some reason re-map the redux state to React's state, you can do so by adding

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.data.data.email !== this.props.data.data.email) {
        this.setState({ email: nextProps.data.data.email });
    }
}
```

to your `Profil` component.